# How does a host know automatically that on which port number a specific server is listening?

Tags: port

I know DNS tells the IP address of a web address. But how does a client know that on which port that specific website is listening on? Similarly for other services like FTP, Telnet and SMTP. I know HTTP, HTTPS, SMTP,FTP, Telnet have well known ports but **Gmail smtp** doesn't listen on a **well known smtp port**.

**Does my PC beforehand all the port numbers of all the servers (web,FTP,smtp etc.)? Or it contacts some service like DNS to query it**

Comment: 465 and 587 ARE standard ports for SMTP over TLS. Google doesn't use 25 because they require TLS. Note that if an SMTP client doesn't automatically check 465/587, you will have to configure your client to use it .  I don't believe DNS ever answers questions about ports.  https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp#:~:text=The%20outgoing%20SMTP%20server%2C%20smtp,before%20issuing%20the%20STARTTLS%20command.

Comment: Normally, clients use [standard service port numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). In UNIX boxes, they are often listed in the file `/etc/services`. However, DNS can be used to list IP addresses and port numbers for services in your network, using [SRV records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record). In short, both parts of the last paragraph are correct. Often though, servers listen at non-standard ports that have no SRV record either. In this case, the client must be configured or operated accordingly.

Comment: please give your evidence that it "knows automatically"   It doesn't. Like, who knew that http://google.com should go to port 80?  When every other http://blah.com with no   port specified does"  So it doesnt take mystic meg to guess the browser will go to port 80 there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clients *do not know* what port to connect to on a server.  The main reason is that a server can typically run a service (web, mail, ftp, etc) on *any* port.  There *are* standardized ports for services.  See this Wikipedia article for a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).   A server administrator can choose to run a website on port 80, which is standard, or any other port of his choosing, as long as another service isnt already bound to that port.

Most clients default to the standard port for their use.  For example, when you type http://somewebsite.com into your browser, the browser assumes port 80.  This isnt magic, as the 80 is the standard and *someone* programmed the browser to go to that port by default.  You can type http://somewebsite.com:80 in your browser and this explicitly tells the browser to go to port 80.  If the server administrator set up the web server to run on port 12345 and you went to http://somewebsite.com, the site would not come up.  You specifically have to tell the browser to go to http://somewebsite.com:12345.

Comment: So the 'LIST' you referred is saved with in my OS?

Comment: @AJHUNTER No.  Reread the answer.

Comment: @AJHUNTER, you are confusing the software clients (for email, think Outlook or Thunderbird, or Eudora if you're old like me) with the OS. The OS has lots of clients built into it which will know standard ports for their particular application protocols, and/or provide configuration to allow you to set them, but it doesn't have a "list" of protocol/port mappings. the clients built into it will know how to do their thing, but if you don't have a client for a rando protocol no one has used for decades, your OS won't know or care a whit about it. the OS leaves this to its individual applications.

Comment: So at random any client end application protocol will have to know beforehand which port to use to connect to a server.
If a web server user a random listening port number, my web browser won't open it.
Am I right?

Comment: @AJHUNTER Yes.  Browsers are programmed to go to the default of 80, but if a webserver is running on 3333 it will have no way of knowing

Answer (score 2):

> How does a client know which port that specific website is listening on?

Ports are often hard-coded into the program itself (e.g. specifying `http://` or `https://` in a browser without additional port information) or defined by users through the program's interface (e.g. for many FTP/email clients, where a service provider tells the user what ports to use).

[SRV records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) (which do operate through DNS zones) are the exception to this, but my impression is that they are often used in a limited fashion.

> I know HTTP, HTTPS, SMTP, FTP, Telnet have well known ports but Gmail SMTP doesn't listen on a well-known SMTP port.

As noted in the comments, [Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en) does use well-known, widely accepted email ports. Ports 465 and 587 (SMTP), as well as 993 (IMAP), are all used by major email providers (e.g. Yahoo, Comcast, etc.) in place of older ports for the same services when dealing with clients.

Comment: Specifically, 25 is the well-known "Mail exchange" (SMTP server-to-server) port, while 587 and recently 465 are the well-known "Mail submission" (SMTP client-to-server) ports. The distinction didn't exist *at first,* which is why only 25 got the "smtp" name, but the separation is now well established.